# What is the best way to implement the graphics for a selected item in a WPF user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, user-interface

I have implemented a few different WPF user controls.  In doing so I have also implemented a few different ways of implementing the graphics for when an item is selected.

I want to find out how others are doing this and what they think is the best way of doing it?

Only one solution per answer please.

To avoid confusion here are some examples of graphics to indicate that an item is selected:

- Adding graphics to the adorner layer for an element.

  Changing the color of an element based on an 'IsSelected' property in the data.

  Procedurally showing/hiding an element in the XAML that indicates selection.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "implementing the graphics"? Usually an item is rendered with a background of [SystemColors.HighlightBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.highlightbrush.aspx) when it's selected. Any system other than that can be hard to understand for normal users.